# HTML Table random character appears

Tags: html, css

In my website I have a table and when displaying in Chrome or Firefox I get an odd character 'w' appearing without being in the code just before the table displays.

The page in particular is:
http://math.jhu.edu/jmartinezgarcia/conferences.html

It doesn't bother me a lot, but I would like to know why it appears.

Warning: I know that I have a mixture of HTML 4 or even 3 and CSS but somewhat I suspect this may not be the reason.

Comment: Provide your markup language so we can look through your code. Obviously you posted your website and we can see the "w" character loading in your HTML but posting your markup for us will help us determine the proper fix.

Comment: It was a long file. I thought everyone would be able to do 'right click, show code', as it seems.

Comment: Oh, and I couldn't get a shortest file necessary, because the problem came out of its complexity (when erasing the table it disappeared).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a 'w' character in your markup:

```
<tr>w
    <td><b>17-19 December 2009</b></td>
    <td><a href="http://www.mat.ucm.es/~arrondo/workshop/" target="_blank">Workshop on Algebraic Geometry</a>. Madrid, Spain.</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: It's interesting that if you drop a 'w' at some point in between it appears at the top. I've had this error for a really long time (since 2009)! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here it is, line 230 of your html.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I've accepted the previous answer because it arrived earlier and I cannot accept both, but both of you are right, of course.